# Nginx returns 426

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, istio-gateway

When I am accessing a Istio gateway `NodePort` from the Nginx server using `curl`, I am getting response properly, like below:

```
curl -v "http://52.66.195.124:30408/status/200"
*   Trying 52.66.195.124:30408...
* Connected to 52.66.195.124 (52.66.195.124) port 30408 (#0)
> GET /status/200 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 52.66.195.124:30408
> User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: istio-envoy
< date: Sat, 18 Sep 2021 04:33:35 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-credentials: true
< content-length: 0
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
< 
* Connection #0 to host 52.66.195.124 left intact
```

The same when I am configuring through Nginx proxy like below, I am getting `HTTP ERROR 426` through the domain.

Note: my domain is HTTPS - https://dashboard.example.com

```
server {
        server_name dashboard.example.com;
        location / {
               proxy_pass       http://52.66.195.124:30408;
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP 426 error means [upgrade required](https://httpstatuses.com/426):

> The server refuses to perform the request using the current protocol but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different protocol.

or [another info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426):

> The HTTP **`426 Upgrade Required`** client error response code indicates that the server refuses to perform the request using the current protocol but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different protocol.

In your situation, you need to check what version of the HTTP protocol you are using. It seems too low. Look at [this thread](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2506). In that case, you had to upgrade from `1.0` to `1.1`.

You need to upgrade your HTTP protocol version in NGINX config like there:

> This route is for a legacy API, which enabled NGINX cache for performance reason, but in this route's proxy config, it missed a shared config  [`proxy_http_version 1.1`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version), which default to use HTTP 1.0 for all NGINX upstream.
>
> And Envoy will return  `HTTP 426`  if the request is  `HTTP 1.0`.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue but after adding the proxy_http_version 1.1 to the particular path in nginx conf file, i am getting 404 error on that path. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: was this ever solved ? @ShaswatLenka

Comment: yes, this was solved. This was not due to nginx, the above solution indeed works.

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved the issue adding proxy_http_version 1.1;